# Unable to get value of selected name in textbox

Tags: angularjs

I am getting response from server and storing it to taxes variable i my code I am getting name of tax in first dropdown list and I also want to show corresponding value to show in next text box but it is not working.

```js
   var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('addProductController', function ($scope, $http) {
  
  $scope.taxes =[
{id: 43, name: "a", value: 2}
{id: 44, name: "c", value: 1}
];
};
```

```html
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
</script>
 <div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="addProductController" 
>
<select name="e[$index].name" ng-model=" e[$index].name" ng-options="e.name 
as e.name for e in taxes" class="form-control" ng-required="true"></select>
                            <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="taxes.
[$index].value" class="form-control" ng-required="true" ng-value="e.value">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default 
btn-sm" ng-click="removeChoice($index)">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus">
</span> REMOVE
                            </button>
                            </div>
```

How to get value of selected name in textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ng option assign the whole object to the `ng-model` and access it.

```
<select name="name" ng-model="selected" ng-options="e as e.name for e in taxes" class="form-control" ng-required="true"></select>
<input type="text" name="name" ng-model="selected.value" class="form-control" ng-required="true" ng-value="e.value">
```

Demo

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('addProductController', function ($scope, $http) {
  
  $scope.taxes =[
{id: 43, name: "a", value: 2},
{id: 44, name: "c", value: 1}
];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
 <div class="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="addProductController" >
<select name="name" ng-model="selected" ng-options="e as e.name for e in taxes" class="form-control" ng-required="true"></select>
                            <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="selected.value" class="form-control" ng-required="true" ng-value="e.value">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="removeChoice($index)">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span> REMOVE
                            </button>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Yes it is Working.

Comment: nice. make sure to check as answer if this helped :).

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>icecream</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function choose(){
        var x=myform.select.value;
        if(x=="vanilla"){
            myform.input.value="you picked["+x+"]";
        }
        else if(x=="strawberry"){
            myform.input.value="you picked["+x+"]";
        }
        else if(x=="chocolate"){
            myform.input.value="you picked["+x+"]";
        }
        else if(x=="kesar pista"){
            myform.input.value="you picked["+x+"]";
        }
        else{
            myform.input.value="you picked["+x+"]";
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="myform">
        <select name="select" onclick="choose()">
            <option>ICECREAM FLAVOUR</option>
            <option value="vanilla">vanilla</option>
            <option value="strawberry">strawberry</option>
            <option value="chocolate">chocolate</option>
            <option value="kesar pista">kesar pista</option>
            <option value="blueberry">blueberry</option>
        </select>
        <input  name="input" id="input" value=""/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```